# Using JsZipUtils with NPM & React - file can't be imported

Tags: reactjs, npm, importerror, jszip

I have installed [JsZipUtils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip-utils) via NPM and tried to import it like this:

`import JSZipUtils from 'jszip-utils';`

But the file can not be found. Also it's not mentioned in the documentation how I can import it within React.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating my own local script and importing it like this:

`import JSZipUtils from './JsZipUtils';`

If anyone needs it, here it is:

```
var JSZipUtils = {};
// just use the responseText with xhr1, response with xhr2.
// The transformation doesn't throw away high-order byte (with responseText)
// because JSZip handles that case. If not used with JSZip, you may need to
// do it, see https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Handling_binary_data
JSZipUtils._getBinaryFromXHR = function (xhr) {
  // for xhr.responseText, the 0xFF mask is applied by JSZip
  return xhr.response || xhr.responseText;
};

// taken from jQuery
function createStandardXHR() {
  try {
    return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (e) {}
}

function createActiveXHR() {
  try {
    return new window.ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
  } catch (e) {}
}

// Create the request object
var createXHR =
  typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.ActiveXObject
    ? /* Microsoft failed to properly
       * implement the XMLHttpRequest in IE7 (can't request local files),
       * so we use the ActiveXObject when it is available
       * Additionally XMLHttpRequest can be disabled in IE7/IE8 so
       * we need a fallback.
       */
      function () {
        return createStandardXHR() || createActiveXHR();
      }
    : // For all other browsers, use the standard XMLHttpRequest object
      createStandardXHR;

/**
 * @param  {string} path    The path to the resource to GET.
 * @param  {function|{callback: function, progress: function}} options
 * @return {Promise|undefined} If no callback is passed then a promise is returned
 */
JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent = function (path, options) {
  var promise, resolve, reject;
  var callback;

  if (!options) {
    options = {};
  }

  // backward compatible callback
  if (typeof options === 'function') {
    callback = options;
    options = {};
  } else if (typeof options.callback === 'function') {
    // callback inside options object
    callback = options.callback;
  }

  if (!callback && typeof Promise !== 'undefined') {
    promise = new Promise(function (_resolve, _reject) {
      resolve = _resolve;
      reject = _reject;
    });
  } else {
    resolve = function (data) {
      callback(null, data);
    };
    reject = function (err) {
      callback(err, null);
    };
  }

  /*
   * Here is the tricky part : getting the data.
   * In firefox/chrome/opera/... setting the mimeType to 'text/plain; charset=x-user-defined'
   * is enough, the result is in the standard xhr.responseText.
   * cf https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Receiving_binary_data_in_older_browsers
   * In IE <= 9, we must use (the IE only) attribute responseBody
   * (for binary data, its content is different from responseText).
   * In IE 10, the 'charset=x-user-defined' trick doesn't work, only the
   * responseType will work :
   * http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Binary_Object_upload_and_download
   *
   * I'd like to use jQuery to avoid this XHR madness, but it doesn't support
   * the responseType attribute : http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11461
   */
  try {
    var xhr = createXHR();

    xhr.open('GET', path, true);

    // recent browsers
    if ('responseType' in xhr) {
      xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    }

    // older browser
    if (xhr.overrideMimeType) {
      xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function (event) {
      // use `xhr` and not `this`... thanks IE
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status === 0) {
          try {
            resolve(JSZipUtils._getBinaryFromXHR(xhr));
          } catch (err) {
            reject(new Error(err));
          }
        } else {
          reject(
            new Error(
              'Ajax error for ' +
                path +
                ' : ' +
                this.status +
                ' ' +
                this.statusText
            )
          );
        }
      }
    };

    if (options.progress) {
      xhr.onprogress = function (e) {
        options.progress({
          path: path,
          originalEvent: e,
          percent: (e.loaded / e.total) * 100,
          loaded: e.loaded,
          total: e.total,
        });
      };
    }

    xhr.send();
  } catch (e) {
    reject(new Error(e), null);
  }

  // returns a promise or undefined depending on whether a callback was
  // provided
  return promise;
};

// export
module.exports = JSZipUtils;
```

Comment: Please give a feedback why you're disliking my answer so I can improve it.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was loading fine but `TypeScript` was complaining. I just used `// @ts-ignore`. So the import looked like this:

```js
// @ts-ignore
import * as JSZipUtils from 'jszip-utils';
```